# How to refresh View if @Bindig object property was changed?

Tags: swift, binding, swiftui

I have a two classes:

```
class Glyph: ObservableObject {
    ...
    @Published var manager: CoordinatesManager {
        didSet {
            print ("MANAGER DID SET IN GLYPH, \(manager.currentCoordinates)")
        }
    }

    @Published var elements: [ MultidimensionalPoints ]

    var path: Path {
        var resultPath = Path()
        if self.elements.count > 1 {
            //count path, path elements depends on manager.currentCoordinates
            }
        }
        return resultPath
    }

}

class CoordinatesManager {
    ...
    @Published var currentCoordinates: [ Coordinate ]
    ...
}
```

And now I try to build SwiftUI view hierarchy. In one view I need to show `Glyph` object, in another some sliders to change `manager.currentCoordinates`. Of course each change should be reflected in first view because it changes `glyph.manager.currentCoordinates`.

```
public struct ContentView: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var glyph: Glyph
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GlyphView()
            VStack {
                CoordinatesView(coordinates: $glyph.manager.currentCoordinates)
                Text ("updated manager coordinates\(glyph.manager.currentCoordinates.description)").controlSize(.mini)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CoordinatesView is nothing special: just sliders and it works.  `glyph.manager` `didSet` prints changed values.

```
MANAGER DID SET IN GLYPH, ["width" <min>, "weight" <min>, "contrast" <min>]
MANAGER DID SET IN GLYPH, ["width" 1.72, "weight" <min>, "contrast" <min>]
MANAGER DID SET IN GLYPH, ["width" 3.45, "weight" <min>, "contrast" <min>]
....
```

GlyphView:

```
public struct GlyphView: View
{       
    @EnvironmentObject var glyph: Glyph
    
    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // This is called only when i change View size
            // GlyphShape generates some Shape based on Glyph.currentState
            GlyphShape(glyph: glyph).stroke()
            Text("Overlay for test")
        }
    }
}
```

**This view should react for changes in `glyph.manager.currentCoordinates`** but it doesn't and I don't know how to do it. **Reacts only when I change view size** (by mouse)

```
struct GlyphShape: Shape

{
    @ObservedObject var glyph: Glyph
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let glyphPath = glyph.path
        ... // transform
        print ("MAKING SHAPE @\(glyph.manager.currentCoordinates) \(resultPath)")
        return resultPath
    }
}
```

Every time I scroll (not just move) cursor above Navigator view `func path(in: rect)` in GlyphShape is fired and prints actual `manager.currentCoordinates` and new path in terminal.

```
MAKING SHAPE @["width" <min>, "weight" <min>, "contrast" 29.94] TransformedShape<Path>(shape: 50 70 m 158.264 295.569 l 150 100 l 650 410 l, transform: __C.CGAffineTransform(a: 1.0433333333333332, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 1.0433333333333332, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0)) CCC
MAKING SHAPE @["width" <min>, "weight" <min>, "contrast" 29.94] TransformedShape<Path>(shape: 50 70 m 158.264 295.569 l 150 100 l 650 410 l, transform: __C.CGAffineTransform(a: 1.0433333333333332, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 1.0433333333333332, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0)) CCC
```

Path is redefined, but view isn't refreshed.

How I should tell Glyph that manager.coordinates are changed and reflect it in GlyphView?

Here is a Playground file, simplified.

```
import AppKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

let nibFile = NSNib.Name("MyView")
var topLevelObjects : NSArray?

Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(nibFile, owner:nil, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects)
let views = (topLevelObjects as! Array<Any>).filter { $0 is NSView }

// Present the view in Playground
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = views[0] as! NSView


protocol AxisProtocol {
    var name: String {get}
    var bounds: ClosedRange<Double> {get}
}
struct Axis: AxisProtocol {
    var name: String
    var bounds: ClosedRange<Double>
}

struct Coordinate<Axis:AxisProtocol> {
    var axis: Axis
    var at: Double
}

class CoordinatesManager {
    @Published var currentCoordinates: [ Coordinate<Axis> ]
    init (at: [Coordinate<Axis>]) {
        self.currentCoordinates = at
    }
}

class ItsCompliacated {
    func getSomeValue(at: [Coordinate<Axis>]) -> NSPoint {
        //Counting this value is rather comlicated thing...
        return NSPoint(x: Double.random(in: 0...500), y: Double.random(in: 0...500))
    }
}

class Glyph: ObservableObject {
    @Published var manager: CoordinatesManager {
        didSet {
print (manager)
}
    }
    var elements: [ ItsCompliacated ] = []
    var path: Path {
        var result = Path()
        if elements.count > 1 {
            result.addLines(elements.map({$0.getSomeValue(at: manager.currentCoordinates)}))
        }
        return result
    }
    
    init (elements:[ItsCompliacated], manager:CoordinatesManager) {
        self.manager = manager
        self.elements = elements
    }
}

let x = Axis(name: "x", bounds: 0...1000)
let y = Axis(name: "y", bounds: 0...1000)
let z = Axis(name: "z", bounds: 0...1000)

let cx = Coordinate(axis: x, at: 100)
let cy = Coordinate(axis: y, at: 200)
let cz = Coordinate(axis: z, at: 200)

let manager = CoordinatesManager(at: [cx, cy, cz])
let glyph = Glyph(elements: Array(repeating: ItsCompliacated(), count: 300), manager: manager)

public struct NavigatorView: View
    
{
    @EnvironmentObject var glyph: Glyph
    
    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GlyphShape(glyph: glyph).stroke()
        }
    }
}
public struct CoordinateView : View {
    @Binding var coordinate: Coordinate<Axis>
    public var body : some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0 ) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                Text(coordinate.axis.name).font(.system(size: 8))
                Spacer(minLength: 5)
                Text("\(String(format: "%.2f", coordinate.at))").font(.system(size: 8))
            }
            Slider(value: $coordinate.at, in: coordinate.axis.bounds)
                .controlSize(.mini)
                .labelsHidden()
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: -8, leading: 0, bottom: -10, trailing: 0))
        }
    }
}

public struct CoordinatesView  : View {
    @Binding var coordinates: [Coordinate<Axis>]
    public var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0 ) {
            List ((0..<coordinates.count), id:\.self) { coordinateIndex in
                CoordinateView(coordinate: self.$coordinates[coordinateIndex])
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GlyphShape: Shape {
    
    @ObservedObject var glyph: Glyph
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let glyphPath = glyph.path
        
        print ("MAKING SHAPE")
        
        return glyphPath
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var glyph: Glyph
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigatorView()
                .frame(width: 500, height: 500, alignment: .top)
        
                CoordinatesView(coordinates: $glyph.manager.currentCoordinates)
                    .frame(minWidth: 500, idealWidth: 500, maxWidth: 500, minHeight: 300, idealHeight: .none, maxHeight: 500, alignment: .bottom)

            
            //.frame(minWidth: .none, idealWidth: 500, maxWidth: .none, minHeight: .none, idealHeight: .none, maxHeight: .none, alignment: .bottom)
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView().environmentObject(glyph))
```

Comment: State is for internal private state for a view Binding is when you have a parent with State and you want to pass that state to child view you mark that as Binding .publish is for when you have viewmodel and model and you want to notify a view that model has changed

Answer (score 0):

Glyph and CoordinatesManager should conform to `ObservableObject`.

Also don't see where they are initialized.

If you pass down `manager` instead of `glyph.manager`, then obviously `glyph` is not going to get notified.

Just use `@EnvironmentObject` so you don't have to pass Binding all over the place.

Flatten your struture, e.g.; glyph and manager on same level instead of being nested. Might simplify your debug.

Comment: I have many glyphs and one manger. In protocol which Glyph conforms to, manager is  {get} only. I can change (global) current coordinates in manager, glyphs just use them to generate current shape. Will try with @EnvironmentObject...

Comment: Works similar. Sliders change manager.currentCoordinates, GlyphShape returns changed path, but view reacts only when I resize it.

Comment: If I need CoordinatesView for different (not only manager) coordinates, flattening will be OK?

Comment: I was under the impression that you can't publish a computed property? Show more details, it's hard to track codes that don't seem to compile. How objects are initialized is important too.

Comment: The way I see it. Make a `final class EnvObj: ObservableObject {@Published var coordinate: Coordinate<Axis>}`. Everyone observes this.  Cut every middle man.

Comment: For now manager and glyph are initialized in AppDelegate, as a var (not @Publishers or whatever), glyph is passed in `window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(selectedGlyph!))`

Comment: could you be so nice and explain me more about `EnvObj` class? When I simply copy/paste compiler complains `Class 'EnvObj' has no initializers` (it's class). But even I add init I don't know how to use it...

Comment: I added Playground to the post. You can how it doesn't work now ;)

Comment: Well, you have to initialize it with your use case.  But given with more info, it looks like view is re-rendered since `path:` function in `GlyphShape` is called.  Add breakpoint to make sure. If the view is re-rendered as intended, then it's not about observer. Maybe your `GlyphShape` did not draw it right, and you need to check your calculation. I'd suggest writing a simple unit test without all the complexities. Use `final class EnvObj: ObservableObject {@Published var coordinate = [cy, cy, cz]}` as environment object. That is all you need for testing.

Answer (score 0):

OK. The Error was in `GlyphShape`. Instead of `@BindningObject` should be `@EnvironmentObject`.

So `NavigatorView` should call

```
GlyphShape(glyph: _glyph).stroke()
```

That's all for this.